# Numeric only textbox not working IME enabled

Tags: jquery, textbox, numeric

I am using the following function to make a text box numeric only

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".numeric_text_box").keydown(function(event) {

    if(event.keyCode==9)
  return true;
 if(event.shiftKey)
    event.preventDefault();
if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
  }
else {
      if (event.keyCode < 95) {
       if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
            event.preventDefault();
      }
    } 
    else {
          if (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105) {
              event.preventDefault();
          }
    }
  }
  });
});
```

And my text box is

```
        <input type="text" style="ime-mode:disabled" maxlength="100" name="txt_1" class="numeric_text_box" value="">
```

My problem is ,When system language changes to japanese,I unable to enter integer values in my text box using google Chrome.Is there any solution?

Comment: As your said , you can only enter numeric value in textbox ?

Comment: Yes,I need to enter numeric characters in the textbox even IME is enabled.Because my client is using japanese

Comment: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_events_imehandler.js.source.html   search that document for the word chrome. Theres only one instance of it, i think thats your problem

Comment: How to include this in my code?Can you give an example?